# Question about isometries in $\mathbb{E}^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was looking at the following question.

Given two non-parallel lines $l$ and $l'$ in $\mathbb{E}^2$. Show that there exist exactly 4 isometries that map $l$ to $l'$ and for which the point $x_0$ with $l \cap l' = \{x_0\}$ is a fixed point.

**My attempt:**

*Using the classification theorem for isometries in $\mathbb{E}^2$, it would suffice to show that there are exactly 0 translations, exactly 2 rotations and 2 glide reflections which meet the conditions.*

*Suppose there is a translation $t_b$ that satisfies the conditions. Then because $x_0$ is fixed, $t_b(x_0) = x_0 + b = x_0$ which implies $b = 0$. But then $t_b$ is the identical map which would imply $l = l'$. This contradicts the assumption that the lines are not parallel.*

*Now suppose that $F$ is a rotation that satisfies the conditions. Start by noticing that then $x_0$ is necessarily the center of the rotation because the only fixed point of a rotation is its center. Now my idea was to prove that the only angles of the rotation that  satisfy the conditions would be the two angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ with $\cos(\theta_{1,2}) = \frac{r \cdot s}{\lVert r \rVert \lVert s \rVert}$ where $r$ and $s$ are the directions of the lines $l$ and $l'$ respectively. Visually this would be logical. I seem to be stuck however at this point.*

*Showing that there are exactly two glide reflections satisfying the conditions visually makes sense to me but I also seem to be stuck showing that this is the case.*

A very similar question was also asked here [Formally showing that there exist exactly four isometries of $\mathbb{E}^2$ that map two intersecting lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604159/formally-showing-that-there-exist-exactly-four-isometries-of-mathbbe2-that), but the answer didn't seem correct to me. Also here the lines were assumed to be intersecting which doesn't exclude the case where $l = l'$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glide reflections? Why *glide* reflections? Are you sure rotations work in general?

Comment: No I agree you don't need glide reflections and just reflections will do. It's just that the result I'm referring to is that every isometry in 2-dimensional Euclidean space can be classified as either a translation, a rotation or a glide reflection. This also includes regular reflections of course.

Comment: Of course? I always distinguish between a reflection (a line of fixed points) and a glide reflection (no fixed point)!

Comment: Ahhh I see. In my geometry course we allow translations to just translate by the zero vector, which allows regular reflections in the definition of glide reflections. I wasn't aware that this is perhaps not the most common convention. This shouldn't however change the way to solve the problem since the only two "glide reflections" that I was hoping to show that satisfy the condition should indeed as you say be regular reflections.

Comment: And draw some pictures of your rotation idea, while you’re at it.